# proper way to handle data returned by stored procedure in entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, entity

I keep on encountering this error

> The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have
>   enough columns for the query requested.

I have tried different ways on how to handle the return but none of them works.

```
var r = myDb.spInsertBankDeposit(accountNumber, serialID,
                                 payer, transferFrom, decimal.Parse(depAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                 remarks, fulldate, time,tradingCh, 2);
```

^ this one is call straight from the DB entity `myDB`, I tried with `.FirstOrDefault()`, `ToList()`, `ToString()` - same error

```
public string InsertBankDeposit(DepositTransactionModel m)
    {
        return DO_DB.spInsertBankDeposit(m.AccountNumber, m.SerialCode, m.AppliedAccountName, m.AppliedAccountNumber, decimal.Parse(m.DepositAmount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                            m.Remarks, m.TransactionDate, m.TransactionTime, m.TradingChannel, m.PlatformID).FirstOrDefault().Msg;
    }
```

^ this also doesn't work when I call `var r = spInsertBankDeposit(model)`

I cannot show the whole sp, but this is the last line.. `SELECT 'Success|Deposit transaction saved successfully!' AS [Msg]`

**UPDATE/EDIT:**
The method `InsertBankDeposit` is being called by here:
[image]

^ this works fine. But when I call the same InsertBankDeposit inside the `dr.Reader()` loop like this:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
       var r = spInsertBankDeposit(model);
       //string s = spInsertBankDeposit(model);
    }
```

I always end up here with the error stated above.[image]

Here is the sp from the entity. Also tried with Scalar String. Same error.
[image]

[image]

I am wondering what's the problem as I have a method that calls the same function `InsertBankDeposit` that works fine. I get the error when I call it inside the loop of reader of an excel file.

Comment: did you try to check the column of excel file compare to the column of your table? also check your excel file carefully.

Comment: The stored procedure returns on one single string and you have mapped the stored procedure to an entity. That's how it doesn't work. You need to map the stored procedure to the proper type. Here in your case it will be a string.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch I just read through the data from the excel file, put it in a variable, then insert using sp. I dont see the reason comparing the tables since I am only extracting data.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya in the code I posted, I used complex type to return [Msg], nonetheless, it was returning as string first, still the same error that's why I tried the complex type, sadly doesnt work too.

Comment: Can you show your SP here?

Comment: Complex type won't work for sure. Can you share the code which is using mapping to string?

Comment: hi, I added more details to my question. that's probably all I can share. let me know if u need anything else as I cannot post the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility that could cause the error is if the stored procedure exits early and not return the string you were expecting.  You can test this out by modifying the SP and removing all the extra code and simply return the string.  If this works, then the problem is somewhere inside the code you removed and not in the way you call the SP.

Comment: sadly, it works fine on the stored procedure, with or without the `select 'success' AS [MSG] at the end`

Comment: The SP doesn't have any problem of course when you use to run it in your DB itself. The problem is,  When you use your query in your project solution. If doesn't have any `Select after your SP code` this is gonna be your `Error` because your SP doesn't have any result returned.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I meant, for troubleshooting, you should try changing the SP so that `select 'success' AS [MSG]` is the only code in there.  This way it's guaranteed that the SP always return the string.

Comment: In theory, this should resolve the error you mentioned.  Then work through the code you removed and figure out which part of it was causing the SP to exit early.

Comment: I was late to mark this as answer, silly that we were using the same procedure for all the sp that we have, but we didn't notice that this particular sp doesn't return `[Msg]` on certain part. That's where I get the error that no one is handling the return, because there was no `[Msg]` return. Thanks!